# I'm unable to implement code to retrieve a value outside of a promise

Tags: javascript, json, object, promise

I've read a lot on promises on this site. I'm new to this all and I just can't figure out how to implement everything.

Below is my code. I'm trying to access **varLocationString;** by using **$scope.finalLocation = varLocationString;** But obviously it's empty. Thank you in advance!!

```
angular.module('example.components')
.controller('Locations', ['$scope', 'LocationsService', function ($scope, LocationsService) {       
    
    var varResults;     
    var varCityName;
    var varISOCode;
    var varUseUsersLocation;
    var varLatitude;
    var varLongitude;       
    var varLocationString;
    

    varResults = LocationsService.search([], [], [], 99)        
                    
    varResults.then(results => {
    $scope.array = results;
    var i = 0;
                
    var myobj = JSON.parse($scope.array[i].properties.weatherLocations);        
        
    varCityName = myobj.fieldsets[0].properties[0].value;
    varISOCode = myobj.fieldsets[0].properties[1].value;
    varUseUsersLocation = myobj.fieldsets[0].properties[2].value;
    varLatitude = myobj.fieldsets[0].properties[3].value;
    varLongitude = myobj.fieldsets[0].properties[4].value;          
            
    varLocationString = JSON.parse("{\"fieldsets\":[{\"alias\":\"weatherLocations\",\"collapse\":true,\"isValid\":true,\"properties\":[{\"alias\":\"latitude\",\"value\":" + varLatitude + ",\"editorState\":{},\"isValid\":true}, {\"alias\":\"useUsersLocation\",\"value\":\"" + varUseUsersLocation + "\",\"editorState\":{},\"isValid\":true},{\"alias\":\"longitude\",\"value\":" + varLongitude + ",\"editorState\":{},\"isValid\":true},{\"alias\":\"cityName\",\"value\":\"" + varCityName + "\",\"editorState\":{},\"isValid\":true},{\"alias\":\"isoCode\",\"value\":\"" + varISOCode + "\",\"editorState\":{},\"isValid\":true}]}]}");
        
    i++;        
    
    });             
    
    $scope.finalLocation = varLocationString;
    
}]);

    enter code here
```

Comment: Put the code that depends on it inside the `.then`

Comment: Unfortunately It needs to be outside of the .then.

Comment: Not possible (other than calling a function inside, which is defined outside)

Comment: When it is inside for some reason the \" is removed from the string

Comment: Can you help me with calling the function inside?

Comment: `const fn = () => { ... }; somePromise.then(fn)` or `somePromise.then(() => { /* code */ fn(); });` Doesn't really change much, it's just a different way of writing